# When I use "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/" in switch mediator synapse is getting updated. If I use <switch ..soap-envelope", it does not

Tags: soap, namespaces, apache-synapse

When I use,
 " < switch xmlns:soapenv= " http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/" in switch mediator synapse is getting updated. If I use "< switch xmlns:soapenv= "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope ", it does not.

Why the synapse is not getting updated when I do not have the  / (slash) after soap-envelope when providing it in switch?

This works in any other places like in a proxy, fault mediator etc.

If I use a different namespace rather than soapenv still it works without the / slash.

Pls explain the reason for this behavior.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a bug. The correct namespace URI does not have a `/` at the end. But you may need to provide more context for anyone to be able to tell for sure. What XML are you providing?